# Android Update View after JSONRequest success

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm building an Android app (I'm using Kotlin not JAVA, but if you can get me the Java approach is fine) that's supposed to show the weather information using the OpenWeather API. I already set the view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layCity">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCity"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="PORTO"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCountry"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="(PT)"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layTempDetail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layCity"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtCurTemp"
            android:text="20º"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblMinTemp"
                android:text="Min:"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtMinTemp"
                android:text="10º"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblMaxTemp"
                android:text="Max:"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtMaxTemp"
                android:text="30º"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblPressure"
                android:text="Pressure:"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtPressure"
                android:text="100"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblHumidity"
                android:text="Humidity:"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtHumidity"
                android:text="30%"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I have another class responsible to make the request and change each field individually like this:

```
public fun getCityInfo(name: String){
        val URI = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&appid=", name)
        Log.d("uri", URI)
        var cityName: String = ""
        queue.add(JsonObjectRequest(
                URI,
                null,
                {

                    cityName = it.getString("name")
                    var main = it.getJSONObject("main")
                    var temp: Double = main.getDouble("temp")
                    //getting the rest of the info


//I save the info that I need in a class

                    var currTemp = CurrentTemperature(temp,press,humidity,min,max,state,desc,icon)
                    var city = City(name, currTemp)


//then set each field individually
                    var detailsview = (context as AppCompatActivity).findViewById(R.id.layDetails) as View

                    (detailsview.findViewById(R.id.txtCity) as TextView).setText(city.name)
                    (detailsview.findViewById(R.id.txtCurTemp) as TextView).setText(city.currTemp.curr.toString())
},
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to get weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
```

But what I wanted is to return the city instance on success, then I have some kind of bind in my fields that automatically update the view.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you have a separate class to do the request?

Comment: Also, volley doesn't automatically refresh or bind to any views  unless you tell it to. Which, you've done at `setText(city.name)`, for example. Not really sure I see the need for `var city`

Comment: @cricket_007 just for organization reason. not more then that. I'm new at Android so that's what I wanna know, if there's a way to update an instance lets say, then the view is refresh

Comment: if you see in my view example the initial values are set manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know Kotlin at all, but I'll try to explain enough using Java terms.

Redefine your method to accept the Volley listener as a callback to the Activity.

```
public fun getCityInfo(name: String, callback: Response.Listener<JSONObject>)
```

Then, you call that function, passing in this closure as that `callback`

```
getCityInfo("Chicago", 
{
    var cityName = it.getString("name")
    var main = it.getJSONObject("main")
    var temp: Double = main.getDouble("temp")
    //getting the rest of the info

    var currTemp = CurrentTemperature(temp,press,humidity,min,max,state,desc,icon)
    var city = City(name, currTemp)

    setCity(city) // TODO: implement method within Activity 
})
```

Notice a added `setCity`. You'll need to implement that to update whatever views you have.

Now, in that other class, simply pass along the response listener from the Activity

```
queue.add(JsonObjectRequest(
            URI,
            null, 
            callback, 
            { ... } // error handle
```

Comment: my question is, how can I bind that city instance fields to my "TextView" fields in the view?

Comment: `(findViewById(R.id.txtCity) as TextView).setText(city.name)`... Right?

Comment: If you are trying to ask about this data binding library, I can't help with that.  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: That I know, I was asking if there's a way to just do it automatically. Or that is the more efficient one. I asked this because I usually use ASP.Net MVC and WPF where you do almost everything by binding. Not setting the field

Comment: Okay, yeah, if you draw that comparison, you'll just need that library I linked to. Still, though, this approach of defining the callback will allow you to more easily get the references to the Activity class you called to your weather service from

Comment: ok. thanks for the help. I think I'll go your way then investigate a bit more on the link that you gave ;)